# AGESA Extraction - AMI UEFI

Tags: uefi

Are there any community tools that are aimed specifically at extracting or replacing AGESA code in a UEFI?  In AMI UEFIs, AGESA is said to be scattered among multiple modules.  I have read that in AWARD BIOSes it's contained within a single module.  Are there any modern AWARD AMD UEFIs?

Thank you for any guidance.

Edit: Removed the long intro, straight to business.